# Angular 2 - Passing Components Around

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two grids, lets call `Employees` and `CompanySummary`. Both of these are components and are children of my `AppComponent`.

I have the `Employees` grid setup so that it is editable and the final row of the grid is a summation of the the `Employee's` salaries. Now, in the `CompanySummary` grid, I have a few static rows, but one of the rows is EmployeeSalaries which I want to come from the `Employees` grid.

I have been trying to pass the `Employees` grid over to the `CompanySummary` grid so that I can call `Employees.getTotalSalary()`, but I can't figure out how. In `AppComponent`, is there a way to have a property of type `Employees` (which is bound to the grid) that I can then bind as an Input to `CompanySummary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a local variable that refers to your Employees component and pass it into CompanySummary

AppComponent Template:

```
<employees #emp></employees>
<company-summary [employees]="emp"></company-summary>
```

Comment: So simple and exactly what I needed! I didn't realize that local variables could be used like that. Thank you so much!